# Remove branded shutdown animation

Tags: shutdown

### Does anybody know where the shutdown animation is located in my branded phone?

I don't like this branded stuff, so I'd like to remove it.
It's been simple for the boot animation (it was where Android forums tell to look - `/system/media/bootanimation.zip`).
But for the shutdown animation I still have no clue... It is not located in the standard path `/system/media/video/shutdown`.

> Information on my phone:
>   - Model LG-P692
>   - Android version 2.3.4 (Gingerbread)
>   - Kernel version 2.6.35.10-perf+
>   - Build number GRJ22
>   - SW version V10e-JUN-04-2012

Comment: I've read [this post](http://androidforums.com/connect-4g-all-things-root/552802-shutdown-animations-lg-connect-4g-rooted.html) where someone with an LG Connect 4G couldn't find the shutdown animation in the usual location (`system > media > video > shutdown`). Someone answered that it is located on the ramdisk. Perhaps this is also the case for your phone?

Comment: @THelper: how to locate and change it in the ramdisk?

Comment: I have no experience with that myself, but [this page](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=HOWTO:_Unpack%2C_Edit%2C_and_Re-Pack_Boot_Images#Structure_of_boot_and_recovery_images) may be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**IMPORTANT:** Make a backup before trying any of the following steps!

Usually the animation video is stored at: `/system/media/video/shutdown` You can rename this to something else. Or delete all the files from there.

If it's not there, check `/system/customize/resource/` or `/data/local/` May be it can be found there.

In some cases shutdown animation may be handled by an APK. Check under `system/app` if you have a `Shutdown.apk` or `PowerOff.apk`. If yes (like in LG-P692), you also have `PowerOff.odex` there. *Do NOT touch* `PowerOff.odex`.

In this case you can modify the `PowerOff.apk`. This is how:

1. Copy the `PowerOff.apk`to your PC
2. Use 7zip or WinRAR or any uncompressor software you have, to open the APK. Go to `res/drawable` folders. You might have up to 3-4 of them like: `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-xdpi` (in case of LG-P692, only `drawable-mdpi` will be found).
3. There you can see some `.png` or `.jpg` files. Replace those with any images that you want. If you don't want anything there you can use plain black images. Make sure that you put the images with the same resolution that of the original images. Replace images in all the drawable folders.
4. After you replace those images, make sure the APK is in the same format as it was earlier, except the images that have been changed.
5. Now copy back the `PowerOff.apk` to your phone where it was.
6. Power off your phone. REMOVE your battery. Power on. And now test.

See how this helps.

Tested with an LG-P692.

Comment: I have a rooted LG P500 running stock 2.3.3 (V20C). I do not have folder /system/media/video/shutdown, /system/customize/resource/ and /data/local/

Comment: Yes @SurajBajaj, I have PowerOff.apk in /system/app and it contains 16 files named power_off_001.pro to power_off_016.pro, which appears to be images for animation. It also contains shutdown.mp3 which is being played while shutdown. I am unable find a suitable app (in Windows) to open these power_off_xxx.pro files to verify them.

Comment: The LG P990 (operadora Claro - Brazil) has the aplication PowerOf.apk ... i change the files in res/drawable and perfect !!! Tks